# How do I move dropdown menu below dropdown button with React and Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I am attempting to add a simple element with the intention of it looking like this:

[image: Proper Format]

However, when adding padding, I can't seem to make it appear below the base, like so:

[image: Current]

Here is my CSS:

```
.controls
  .dropdown-menu
    li
      border-top: 1px solid #B3B3B3
      cursor: pointer
      padding-bottom: 1em
      padding-top: 1em
      text-transform: capitalize

      &:hover
        background-color: #EEE

.controls
  section
    margin-bottom: 1em

  .form-control.searching
    background: url(xxx) 240px center no-repeat

  form.pull-right
    padding: 0

  .main .dropdown-component
    display: inline-block
    margin-right: 0.9em

    button:last-child
      min-width: 0

  .dropdown-menu

    margin-top: 50 px
    padding-left: 20 px
```

And here is my control scheme:

```
  render: function render() {
    return (
      <div className="controls col-lg-12">
        <section className="row">
          <div className="col-lg-8">
            <Dropdown
              secondary={this.toggle('showCreateDropdown')}
              caption={this.getIntlMessage('addContact')}
              primary={this.toggleForm('contactForm', 'uploadForm')}
              show={this.state.showCreateDropdown}
              fields={[{
                value: this.getIntlMessage('uploadMultiple'),
                action: this.toggleForm('uploadForm', 'contactForm')
              }]}
              className='dropdownFormat' />
            <a target="_blank"
              data-track="click"
              id="createNewsletter"
              data-action="navigate"
              href={this.props.gemUrl}
              className="btn btn-default newsletter"
              data-label="create-newsletter">
              {this.getIntlMessage('createNewsletter')}
            </a>

            <span className="left-padding">{this.getIntlMessage('totalCount')}: {this.props.count}</span>
          </div>

          <div className="col-lg-4">
            <form className="col-lg-10 pull-right" onSubmit={this.search}>
              <input
                id="searchBar"
                type="text"
                ref="filterTextInput"
                placeholder={this.getIntlMessage('search')}
                className={'form-control' + (this.state.searching ? ' searching' : '')}
                onChange={this.search} />
            </form>
          </div>
        </section>

        {this.renderForm()}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: pls make a fiddle or at least update this one http://jsfiddle.net/ww7zewxx/

Comment: Thank you! What else would be helpful to add beyond what you have already done?

Comment: when i run it i don't see anything

Comment: This is just a small portion of the codebase, I was hoping to not post the entire thing. Is there no way that someone with more experience with dropdowns can diagnose the issue this way?

Comment: well could you at least post the relevant html and correct the css